# Is there a way to merge JSON objects array with another JSON objects array from other some other view/table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So there are these 2 tables I want to group together by age so that i can find the total number of people from that age group from both the tables so far i'm able to achieve it but the way i want the JSON data to be is wrong

This is my approach:

```
SELECT temp.age, sum(temp.total), json_agg(temp.data_recs) as data_recs FROM (

        SELECT  
            '31-40' as age, COUNT(*) as total, 
            json_agg(
                  CASE
                  WHEN table_1.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 
                  THEN json_build_object(
               'country', table_1.country,
               'Name', table_1.name
            )
            ELSE json_build_object(
                  'country', '',
                  'Name', ''
                )
                END
                  ) AS data_recs 
            from table_1 
        WHERE table_1.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  
            '31-40' as age, COUNT(*) as total, 
            json_agg(
                  CASE
                  WHEN table_2.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40
                  THEN json_build_object(
               'country', table_2.country,
               'Name', table_2.name
            )
            ELSE json_build_object(
                  'country', '',
                  'Name', ''
                )
                END
                  ) AS data_recs 
            from table_2 
        WHERE table_2.age BETWEEN 31 AND 40

  ) AS temp group by temp.age
```

result from 1'st table eg.

```
  age  |  total |  data_recs
'31-40'|   2    | [{"name":"John","country":"USA"},{"name":"Eddy","country":"USA"}]
```

result from 2'nd table eg.

```
  age  |   total |  data_recs
'31-40'|   2     | [{"name":"Cienna","country":"Italy"},{"name":"Rosie","country":"Italy"}]
```

So far I'm able to achieve

```
  age  |   total |  data_recs
'31-40'|   4     | [[{"name":"John","country":"USA"},{"name":"Eddy","country":"USA"}],[{"name":"Cienna","country":"Italy"},{"name":"Rosie","country":"Italy"}]]
```

JSON array 1 = `[{"name":"John","country":"USA"},{"name":"Eddy","country":"USA"}]`

JSON array 2 = `[{"name":"Cienna","country":"Italy"},{"name":"Rosie","country":"Italy"}]`

What I want is :-

```
     age  |   total |  data_recs
  '31-40' |   4     | [{"name":"John","country":"USA"},{"name":"Eddy","country":"USA"},{"name":"Cienna","country":"Italy"},{"name":"Rosie","country":"Italy"}]
```

comibined JSON what i want Should be like this:

```
[{"name":"John","country":"USA"},{"name":"Eddy","country":"USA"},{"name":"Cienna","country":"Italy"},{"name":"Rosie","country":"Italy"}]
```

Is there a way to do this or any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you code is as follows

```
SELECT
    json_agg(json_objects from UNION)
FROM (
    SELECT
        json_agg(
            json_build_object()
        )
    FROM
        ...

    UNION

    SELECT
        json_agg(
            json_build_object()
        )
    FROM
        ...
)
```

So first you are creating arrays and afterwards you are aggregating the arrays. But if you would leave out your first `json_agg()` steps, then the high-level `json_agg()` would aggregate the JSON objects you are creating with `json_object_build()`.

So, only do one aggregation should be your solution:

```
SELECT
    json_agg(json_arrays from UNION)
FROM (
    SELECT
        json_build_object()
    FROM
        ...

    UNION

    SELECT
        json_build_object()
    FROM
        ...
)
```

Comment: is it possible to get the result without removing json_agg() from the inside and then use some unnest function ?

Comment: Well, I can't see any way which seems to make sense. Of course, you can use your inner json_agg() and unnest the elements afterwards using json_array_elements(). But why should you do this: aggregating only to inverse this operation right after... This could be the code: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4782857ab2ced5c0ee02defec86f4ca8